# AJAX Success function and Error function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/product/addproduct")]
    public IActionResult AddProduct([FromBody] string[] addproduct)
    {
      var pProductName= addproduct[0];
      var pProductDetail= addproduct[1];
      var pProductCategory= addproduct[2];

      Hotel NewProduct = new Product();
      {
          NewProduct.ProductName= pProductName;
          NewProduct.ProductDetail= pProductDetail;
          NewProduct.ProductCategory= pProductCategory;
      }

      _db.Products.Add(NewProduct);
      _db.SaveChanges();

      //create a new route for post method by id

            return Json(new{success=true}); //what should I return here to make AJAX return a success function
    }
```

This is my AJAX that I need to return Success instead of error:

```
  $(function postProduct() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {

  var contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  var productName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var productDetail = document.getElementById("detail").value;
  var productCategory = document.getElementById("category").value;

var dimensions = [productName, productDetail, productCategory];
      var keys = $.map(dimensions, function(value, key) {
        return value;
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/product/addproduct",
    data: JSON.stringify(keys),
dataType:'json' ,
    contentType: contentType,
    success: function(result) {
      alert('successful : ' + result);
      return result;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Not Working..");
    }
  });
}

  });
```

This function successfully passes my form to my controller and save it into the database. However, my ajax kept returning the function error which is alerting the message (Not Working..). I tried returning many different ways in my c# controller, however, ajax still returns me an error message. What should I do in my controller in order to let ajax return the success function? HELP

An additional question is after ajax returns success function how can I direct to the main page with an alert message that will tell us the new product is added. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I added in my controller which will match the data type in ajax but I'm still getting the error instead of the success function:

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewProduct);
        return Json(new { json });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the action method you need to add 
**JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet**
in the Json result as the 2nd parameter

eg.

```
return Json(new {success="true"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet )
```

Comment: I think this method is only for asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can return in following two ways from action method:

1. If we want to return any object and the object value should not be null.
   return Json(NewProduct, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
2. return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);